# Implement your own Thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was asked at an interview today about how I would implement my own Thread. As a hint I was told that implmenting Runnable was one thing to consider, and what are the others?

I was completely stumped but even after researching it online, I still have no idea what the answer is or if it was even a valid question. I'm leaning towards the latter.

So my question is:

What things would you need to consider if you wanted to write your own implementation of the Thread class in C#?

Comment: There is no `Runnable` interface in C#.

Comment: Thread is a lower level primitive than c#'s `Runnable` equivalent, `Task`. Arguably, Runnable is actually equivalent to `Action` but lets not split hairs. I would ask the interviewer to elaborate on the expectations of such an open ended question.

Comment: Exactly, which leads me to believe this was an invalid question. Is there something similar? It was a clear C# interview so not sure how Runnable from Java popped into it.

Comment: Well the `Thread` class in C# is more or less just wrappers around a bunch of OS API calls.  It is the OS, and not C#, that handles creating multiple threads, scheduling them, managing their memory, etc.  Re-creating all of that C# code would be tedious, but not terribly interesting from a CS perspective.  See for yourself in [the source code for Thread](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs).

Comment: Perhaps the interviewer just meant how to use System.Threading.Thread or perhaps how to subclass a custom thread. Either way, it seems like a poor question. A quick web search makes me think the interviewer was confused with Java/Android.

Comment: Did you hear about .NET Reflector? Of course if you need not simple answer and I hope it's create for you full picture how Thread is work. Hard way, but useful)

Comment: TBH implementing threading on a platform that doesn't support threading seems completely pointless. Look at node.js, that has always been by design thread free.

Comment: @Aron Operating systems implement threading on a platform that doesn't support it.  It's certainly *possible*, it's just *really hard* (to do well).

Comment: Can you clarify the level of position you were interviewing for?

Comment: @Servy I know. You'd have to start up the thread using the Win32 API in the case of windows. I think the hard part would be the inter-thread coms.

Comment: @Gusdor, the role was a senior C# server side developer.

Answer (score -1):

First up, `Runnable` probably refers to `Action`. Action is a delegate type used to store a reference to a method. You use this to tell a thread what method to start on.

I expect they only wanted you to illustrate how to;

- start a thread with a delegate (that is how `Runnable` enters the fray).

-or-

- schedule work to be performed on a worker thread. I would use a call to `Task.Run(new Action(....))` for this. It is concise and modern.

I would always do the latter until instructed to detail the lower level `Thread` class.

Comment: I *highly* doubt the answer to "how would you implement this language construct yourself" is, "use the existing language construct".  The point of the question is what would you do *if you were the person responsible for building that language construct*.

Comment: @Servy do you know that for a fact? The evidence of `Runnable` as a hint is what steered me away from detailing the WINAPI calls that are required.

Comment: Of course I can't know that for a fact.  But the evidence is pretty compelling that the answer to, "how would you implement X from scratch" is not, "don't implement X from scratch".  It's not actually answering the question.  It's refusing to answer it.

Comment: @Servy we have a difference of opinion on what constitutes compelling. Interview questions don't have to be on_the_metal hardcore to be illustrative on a candidates ability.